# Excel, Visual Basic Editor, Enum type declaration - User-defined type not defined

Tags: excel, excel-2007, declaration, vba

I have the following code and I don't know why Excel doesn't see the `Enum` type (that I've declared) in the `Test2()` subroutine:

```
Private Sub Test1()
    Dim test_name As Variant

End Sub


Private Enum rlcRollercoasterState
    rlcRollercoasterDisabled
    rlcRollercoasterEnabled
    rlcRollercoasterBroken
    rlcRollercoasterMissing
End Enum


Private Sub Test2()
    Dim var1 As Variant

    Dim rlcRC1State As rlcRollercoasterState ' User-defined type not defined

End Sub
```

If I copy the `Test1()` subroutine after the `Enum` type declaration, Excel recognizes the `rlcRollercoasterState` type in `Test1()`.
If I comment out the `Test1()` subroutine, Excel recognizes `rlcRollercoasterState` type in `Test2()`.

Why does the Excel fail to see the `rlcRollercoasterState` type in the `Test2()` subroutine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

Always "Debug/Compile VBAProject" (Alt-dl) before running the code. As in your example it give the error. The compile error says it wants the declaration statement at the beginning of the module.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wouldn't have thought about that. I have a theoretical question though: doesn't the program need to be compiled before it is run? (I mean, when I _run_ the program, isn't the _compilation_ of the program the part of the _run_ procedure? - that would mean that the error message should show up even when I _run_ the program, instead of just when I _compile_ the program. I don't quite get it).

Comment: You can select the Compile On Demand check box if you want VBA to compile the code only as needed. VBA compiles the code before running the procedure then. http://books.google.co.in/books?id=n-2NtSJNHBYC&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=You+can+select+the+Compile+On+Demand+check+box+if+you+want+VBA+to+compile+the+code+only+as+needed&source=bl&ots=GHLiuIK82q&sig=b_ub91b56s5OjwdfHtiDzMcOZPw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3bVLUYzHDoWsrAeevYH4DQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=You%20can%20select%20the%20Compile%20On%20Demand%20check%20box%20if%20you%20want%20VBA%20to%20compile%20the%20code%20only%20as%20needed&f=false